# The stack and stack frames in a low level language

Tags: assembly, stack

I'm trying to wrap my head around the concept of function calls as they relate to the stack. This question is being asked in the context of a low level language, not a high level.

From what I understand so far, when a function is called, local variables and parameters get stored in a stack frame on the stack. Each stack frame is associated with a single function call. The part I'm not quite clear on is who is responsible for creating the frame? Is my program supposed to look at the function declaration in the program and copy the local variables over to a new frame on the stack manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes...

Assume you have a language like C that allows recursion.  For that to work each instance of a function must be self contained from other instances of that function.  The stack is the perfect place as code can "allocate" and reference items in the allocation without knowing the physical address, it is all accessed by reference.  All you care about is keeping track of that reference within the context of the function and restoring the stack pointer to where it was when you entered the function.

Now you have to have a calling convention, one that fits recursion, etc.  Two popular choices (using a simplified model) are register passing and stack passing.  You can have and actually will have hybrids in reality (register based you will run out of registers and have to revert to the stack for the remaining parameters).

Assume for a moment that the fictional hardware I am talking about magically handles the return address without messing with registers or the stack.

register passing.  Define a specific set of hardware/processor registers that will hold the parameters, lets say r0 is always the first parameter, r1 the second, r2 the third.  and lets say the return value is r0 (this is simplified).

stack passing.  lets define the first thing you push on the stack is the last parameter, then next to last up to the first parameter.  When you return lets say the return value is the first thing on the stack.

Why declare a calling convention?  So that both the caller and the callee know exactly what the rules are and where to find parameters.  Register passing looks great on the surface, but when you run out of registers you have to save stuff on the stack.  When you want to go from being a callee to a caller of another function, you might have to preserve items in the calling registers so you dont lose those values.  And you are on the stack.

```
int myfun ( int a, int b, int c)
{
    a = a + b;
    b+=more_fun(a,c)
    return(a+b+c);
}
```

a, b, and c are used after the call to more_fun, more_fun at a minimum needs r0 and r1 to pass the parameters a and c and so you need to save r0 and r1 somewhere so that you can 1) use them to call more_fun() and 2) so that you dont lose the values a and b which you will need after you return from more_fun().  you could save them in other registers but how do you protect those registers from being modified by called functions.  Ultimately stuff is saved on the stack, which is dynamic and accessed by reference instead of physical addresses.  so

someone wants to call myfun and we are using register pasing.

```
r0 = a
r1 = b
r2 = c
call myfun
;return value in r0

myfun:
r0 = r0 + r1 (a = a + b)
;save a and b so we dont lose them
push r0 (a)
push r1 (b)
r0 = r0 (a) (dead code, can be optimized out)
r1 = r2 (c)
call more_fun
;morefun returns something in r0
pop r1 (recover b)
r1 = r1 + r0 (b = b+return value)
pop r0 (recover a)
;r0 is used for returning a value from a function
r0 = r0 + r1 (= a+b)
r0 = r0 + r2 (=(a+b)+c)
return
```

The calling function (caller) knows to prepare three parameters in r0, r1, r2 and take a
return value in r0.  The callee knows to accept r0,r1,r2 as incoming parameters and return in r0 AND it knows it has to preserve some things when it becomes the caller to some other function.

And if we use the stack to pass parameters using our calling convention

```
int myfun ( int a, int b, int c)
{
    a = a + b;
    b+=more_fun(a,c)
    return(a+b+c);
}
```

Now we have to make some register rules, do we define the calling rules to say that 1) you can destroy any register (but the sp and pc and psr), 2) that you have to preserve every register such that when you return the calling function never sees its registers changed or do you define 3) that some registers are scratch and can be modified at will and some have to be preserved if used.  I am going to say that you can destroy registers except sp, pc, and spr for simplicity.

We have one more problem to solve.  Who cleans up the stack?  When I call morefun I have two items on the stack going in, and only the return value on the way out, who cleans up the stack.  Two choices, caller cleans, callee cleans,  I go with caller cleans.  Which means the callee has to return from the function with the stack the way it was found, it leave anything on the stack and it doesnt take too many things off the stack.

caller:

```
push c
push b
push a
call myfun
pop result
pop and discard
pop and discard
```

assume with this hardware the stack pointer sp points at the current item on the stack

```
myfun:
;sp points at a
load r0,[sp+0] (get a)
load r1,[sp+1] (get b)
add r0,r1 (a = a+b)
store [sp+0],r0 (the new a is saved)
;prepare call to more_fun
load r0,[sp+2] (get c)
load r1,[sp+0] (get a)
push r0 (c)
push r1 (a)
call more_fun
;two items on stack have to be cleaned, top is return value
pop r0 (return value)
pop r1 (discarded)
;we have cleaned the stack after calling more_fun, our offsets are as
   ;they were when we were called
load r1,[sp+1] (get b)
add r1,r0 (b = b + return value)
store [sp+1],r1
load r0,[sp+0] (get a)
load r1,[sp+1] (get b)
load r2,[sp+2] (get c)
add r0,r1 (=a+b)
add r0,r2 (=(a+b)+c)
store [sp+0],r0 (return value)
return
```

So I wrote all of this on the fly there might be a bug.  The key to all of this is you have to define a calling convention and if everyone (caller and callee) follow the calling convention it makes compiling easy.  The trick is making a working calling convention, as you can see above we had to modify the convention and add rules to make it work even for such a simple program.

What about a stack frame?

```
int myfun ( int a, int b)
{
    int c;
    c = a + b;
    c+=more_fun(a,b)
    return(c);
}
```

using stack based

caller

```
push b
push a
call myfun
pop result
pop and discard
```

callee

```
;at this point sp+0 = a, sp+1 = b, but we need room for c, so
sp=sp-1 (provide space on stack for local variable c)
;sp+0 = c
;sp+1 = a
;sp+2 = b
load r0,[sp+1] (get a)
load r1,[sp+2] (get b)
add r0,r1
store [sp+0],r0 (store c)
load r0,[sp+1] (get a)
;r1 already has b in it
push r1 (b)
push r0 (a)
call more_fun
pop r0 (return value)
pop r1 (discarded to clean up stack)
;stack pointer has been cleaned, as was before the call
load r1,[sp+0] (get c)
add r1,r0 (c = c+return value)
store [sp+0],r1 (store c)(dead code)
sp = sp + 1 (we have to put the stack pointer back to where 
   ;it was when we were called
;r1 still holds c, the return value
store [sp+0],r1 (place the return value in proper place 
   ;relative to callers stack)
return
```

The callee, if it uses the stack and moves the stack pointer, it has to put it back where it
was when it was called.  You create a stack frame by adding the right number of things on the stack for local storage.  You might have local variables and through the process of compiling you may know ahead of time that you have to also preserve a certain number of registers.  The simplest way is to just add all of that up and move the stack pointer one time for the whole function and put it back one time before return.  You can get more clever and keep moving the stack pointer around adjusting offsets as you go, a lot harder to code and more prone to error.  Compilers like gcc tend to move the stack pointer just into the function and return it just before leaving.

Some instructions sets add stuff to the stack on a call and remove it on return and you have to adjust your offsets accordingly.  Likewise your creation and cleanup around a call to another function might require handling related to the hardwares use of the stack if any.

Lets say the hardware when you make a call pushes the return value on the top of the stack.

```
int onefun ( int a, int b )
{
    return(a+b)
}

onefun:
;because of the hardware
;sp+0 return address
;sp+1 a
;sp+2 b
load r0,[sp+1] (get a)
load r1,[sp+2] (get b)
add r1,r2
;skipping over the hardware use of the stack we return on what will be the
;top of stack after the hardware pops the return address
store [sp+1],r1 (store a+b as return value)
return (pops return address off of stack, calling function pops the other two 
   ;to clean up)
```

Some processors use a register to hold a return value when a function is called, sometimes
the hardware dictates which register, sometimes the compiler chooses one and uses it as the
convention.  If your function does not call any other function, you can either not use the return address register and use it for the return, or you can push it on the stack at some point, and then before returning pop it off then use it to return.  If your function does call another function you have to preserve that return address so the call to the next function does not destroy it and you cant find your way home.  so you either save it in another register if you can or put it on the stack

Using the above register calling convention we defined, plus have a register named rx that when a call is made the hardware places the return address in rx for you.

```
int myfun ( int a, int b)
{ 
   return(some_fun(a+b));
}

myfun:
;rx = return address
;r0 = a, first parameter
;r1 = b, second parameter
push rx ; we are going to make another call we have to save the return
        ; from myfun
;since we dont need a or b after the call to some_fun we can destroy them.
add r0,r1 (r0 = a+b) 
;we are all ready to call some_fun first parameter is set, rx is saved
;so the call can destroy it
call some_fun
;r0 is the return from some_fun and is going to be the return from myfun, 
;so we dont have to do anything it is ready
pop rx ; get our return address back, stack is now where we found it 
       ; one push, one pop
mov pc,rx ; return
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically either a processor vendor or the first company to develop popular language compilers for a processor will define what a function caller should do before calling a function (what should be on the stack, what various registers should contain, etc.) and what a called function should do before it returns (including restoring the values of certain registers if they'd been changed, etc.).  For some processors, multiple conventions have become popular and it is generally very important to ensure that the code for any given function will use the convention that the calling code expects.

On the 8088/8086, which had a somewhat small number of registers, two main conventions emerged: the C convention, which specifies that a caller should push arguments onto the stack before calling a function and pop them off afterward (meaning the only thing a called function should pop off the stack is the return address), and the Pascal convention, which specifies that the called function should pop off all of its passed arguments in addition to popping the return address.  On the 8086, the Pascal convention often allows for slightly smaller code (since stack cleanup only needs to happen once for each callable function, instead of once for each function call, and because the 8086 contains a version of RET which adds a specified value to the stack pointer *after* popping the return address.  The one disadvantage of the Pascal convention was that it required the called function to know how many bytes' worth of parameters were going to be passed.  If the called function didn't pop exactly the right number of bytes, stack corruption was almost certain to occur.

On many newer processors, routines which have a small fixed number of parameters generally don't have their parameters pushed on the stack.  Instead, compiler vendors will specify that the first few parameters will be placed into registers before a function is called.  This often allows better performance than would be achieved using stack-based parameters.  Routines with many parameters, or variable argument lists, however, must still use the stack.

Answer (score 0):

To expand a bit on supercat's answer, setting up the stack frame is the shared responsibility of the calling and the called function. The stack frame generally refers to all data that is local to a particular invocation of a routine. The calling routine, then, builds the outer stack frame by first pushing any stack-based parameters onto the stack and then the return address by calling the routine. The called routine then builds the rest of the stack frame (the inner stack frame) by (usually) pushing (saving) the current frame pointer on stack, and setting up a new one that points to the next free stack slot. It then reserves stack for local variables on the stack and, depending on the language being used, might also initialize them at this point. The frame pointer can then be used to access both stack-based parameters and local variables, one with a negative, the other with a positive offset. On exit from the routine, the old stack frame is restored and local data and parameters are popped off, as outlined by supercat.